# Canvas doesn't print my image

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, socket.io

I try to print an image on my canvas when a user is connected.

My code :

```
  socket.on('load', function(x, y, img) {
     var playerimg = new Image();
     playerimg.src = img;
     playerimg.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(playerimg, x, y, 100, 100);
     }
  });
```

The x, y and the variable img are all ok.
I can console.log every value and it's correct but nothing happens on my canvas.

Thanks a lot for your answers

**EDIT :**

The canvas is 100% width, 100% height.
X and Y are equal to 0,0.

Canvas and Context are defined just before :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");    
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Any errors on the console. I've an update function and the x and y are good updated (they change correctly for each player).

Comment: is the canvas large enough to hold image placed at (x,y)? What if (x,y)=(0,0)? Any errors in console? Is something else draw to canvas? Is context correctly initialized? Does the image load properly/correct url (check onerror event)? There is too little code to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Seems I never enter in the playimg.onload function..

Comment: On the onerror event of playerimg, that appears : error { target: <img>, isTrusted: true, currentTarget: <img>, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 1133.215578, cancelBubble: false, originalTarget: <img> }

Comment: try making `playerimg` a global variable

Comment: what when you log this `img` variable, is this really an url string ?

Comment: With playerimg as global variable, I've always the error on the onerror event.

the log of img variable is "img/smiley.png" so seems good !